# i face with This: invalid types `double[int]' for array subscript in my program

Tags: c++, arrays

I was programming with devC++ that i face with this error:
41 J:\Circles.cpp invalid types `double[int]' for array subscript

what should i do to solve this?!!
My code : // i commented the error line (Last part)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
double x_MinMax(int n,double* input);
double xmin;
double xmax;
int main()
{
int n;
cout << "Plz enter n: " << endl;
cin >> n;
double input[3][n];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
               input[i][j]=-1;
                }
        }
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << "Plz enter radius of circle " << n << " : " << endl;
        cin >> input[0][i];
        cout << "Plz enter x of circle " << n << " : " << endl;
        cin >> input[1][i];
        cout << "Plz enter y of circle " << n << " : " << endl;
        cin >> input[2][i];
        }
//circles matrix made:
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                cout << input[i][j] << "  ";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }
x_MinMax(n,*input);        
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
double x_MinMax(int n,double* input){
   int m[1][n];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           m[0][n]= input[1][n] + input[2][n];/// Here is the error Line !!!!!!
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double input[3][n];` is not permitted in C++. Array dimensions must be constant expressions, i.e. resolvable at compile time.

Some compilers allow it as an extension but then you get a snowball effect of non-standard extensions when you try to do things with the array such as pass it to a function.

My advice would be to do this:

```
struct Circle 
{
    double radius, x, y;
};

// ...in main()...
std::vector<Circle> input(n);
// ...
std::cin >> input[0].radius;
```

etc.

A big advantage of using a `struct Circle` instead of an array of 3 doubles is that someone reading your code sees the words `Circle` `radius`, `x`, `y` instead of seeing some brackets the numbers `0`, `1`, `2` and having to try to remember which meaning each number has.

Doing it this way, your code is easy to understand.

We kill two birds with one stone in that `struct` objects can be naturally passed to functions and put into containers - unlike arrays.

You could do away with your loop to initialize everything to `-1` by providing a constructor: (although I'd suggest initializing everything to `0` instead of `-1` makes a bit more sense):

```
Circle(double radius = -1, double x = -1, double y = -1)
    : radius(radius), x(x), y(y) {}
```

Your function would be

```
double x_MinMax(std::vector<Circle> const &input);
```

where you don't have to pass `n` because the information is there in `input.size()`.

It would be easy to generalize your function to an iterator range here too.

Answer (score 1):

In `double x_MinMax(int n,double* input)`, `input` is decleared as a pointer to double.

What would mean `input[1][n]` ?

Try to declare `input` as `double**` and call `x_MinMax(n,input)`.

Bye,

Answer (score 1):

Inside `x_MinMax(int n,double* input)`, the compiler doesn't know the array dimensions of `input` any more, when `double input[3][n]` is passed as `double *`. To use 2-dimensional arrays, the size of the first dimension must be known.